# Can I deactivate this quest in Nukaworld?

Tags: fallout-4

In Nukaworld, I talked with the doctor and accidentally started the quest to kill all the raider bosses. I don't want to do this, but now it won't let me power up Nukaworld until I do. Is there any way to remove or change the quest? I can't reload a save, as the previous save is literally 48 hours of gameplay ago.

Comment: Word of advice: Save

Comment: I understand that, I have always just quick saved over each other for convince.  I didn't know that it would trigger a "kill all" mission; and before i realized i could not get out of it, it was too late to re-load. So i'm coming to all you for help.

Comment: If it helps for the future, if you're in a conversation that looks like it might be "going somewhere" and you don't want it to, just turn your camera. It will "break" the conversation and free you to move around again, and the NPC will just forget you ever talked and be ready to begin the conversation again whenever you choose to talk to them again.

Answer (score 3):

Having this quest doesn't prevent you from anything.
Just complete Nukaworld, and then you will determine if you want to continue this one or not.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to turn on power, you need to conclude the Nuka-World questline in one of two ways:

- Complete [Home Sweet Home](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Home_Sweet_Home) given by [Shank](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Shank). This is the quest where you have to take over settlements for your raider gangs in the Commonwealth
- Complete [Open Season](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Open_Season), the quest given by either Preston (in some circumstances) or [Mackinzie Bridgeman](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Mackenzie_Bridgeman) in [Nuka-World USA Market](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Nuka-Town_market).

The quest doesn't trigger automatically when you complete either of the above. After completion, try and interact with anything in the park that requires power to be on, and you get the quest. I usually try and use the lift in Starport Nuka - as this lift leads you to one of the Star Cores to be found on the map.

You cannot go to the power plant and restore power until you have the quest for it. I tried. Nothing happens.